# Copying vb.net datagrid values to excel with vba sendkeys

Tags: excel, vba, datagrid

I am trying to copy datagridview values to excel, so far, i have this code which works, but only linear

```
Sub Test()
Dim Wkb As Workbook

Set Wkb = ActiveWorkbook
notepadID = Shell("C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\TestInstaller\TestApp.exe")

SendKeys "admin", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "nothing", True

SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
SendKeys "{LEFT}", True
SendKeys ("^C")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
AppActivate "Inventory"
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys ("^C")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

What I would want to do is, copy data from a datagrid, the datagrid composes of 4 rows and 4 columns, i would want to copy everything from the datagrid into my excel using vba sendkeys. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I Know have this code, but the output is diagonal

```
Sub Test()
Dim Wkb As Workbook

Set Wkb = ActiveWorkbook
notepadID = Shell("C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\TestInstaller\TestApp.exe")

SendKeys "admin", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "nothing", True

SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True



Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = 1
j = 1


SendKeys ("^C")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
AppActivate "Inventory"
SendKeys "{TAB}", True



If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
Do While Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j + 3).Value
j = j + 1
SendKeys ("^C")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveCell.Offset(i, j).Select
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
AppActivate "Inventory"
SendKeys "{TAB}", True

If i = 4 Then
i = i = 0
j = j + 1
End If
Loop
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not really experienced with VB and send keys, but can't you just loop trough the cells? For example `ActiveCell.Offsett(y, x).Select`

Comment: @BennoGrimm Sir could you elaborate? i used offset, but the reference is not going beside the cell, its rather going in a diagonal position

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _It works but only linear_?

Comment: in my datagrid on my program, i have 4 columns, i could copy and paste everything on the 1st row. but in the second row, it tends to be in the 1st row of my excel worksheet. it should also be in my 2nd row of my worksheet sir.

Answer (score 0):

So somehow I was able to find the answer on the web, what I was missing was the loop. But somehow, I could not identify dynamically how many rows are there in my Datagridview, I just put a static number. but by far this is the closest thing that I could get.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Wkb As Workbook

Set Wkb = ActiveWorkbook
notepadID = Shell("C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\TestInstaller\TestApp.exe")

SendKeys "admin", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "nothing", True

SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True




Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


i = 1
j = 1


SendKeys ("^C")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
AppActivate "Inventory"
SendKeys "{TAB}", True



If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

Do While Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) <> 13
    j = j + 1
    SendKeys ("^C")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Cells(i, j).Select

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    AppActivate "Inventory"
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True

If j = 4 Then
    i = i + 1
    j = 0
End If

Loop
End If
```

Comment: So as per many posts that i have read, and replies to other forums like this thread, "You could not determine the exact row count in a datagrid because there is no way VBA could inherit the object from any application to its shell, SendKeys could only send of keystrokes, nothing more". So, i just sent sendkeys tab to copy all of the texts in the datagrid, then delete the last row which it would copy, declaring the last row is static.